# How to compare two tensors in tensorflow (not element wise but tensor wise)?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

How to compare two tensors in tensorflow (not element wise but tensor wise),
for example:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0]] 
y = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

expected:

```
not_equal(x, y) --> [True, False]
```

The tf.not_equal(x, y) returns:

```
[[True, True, True, True], [False, False, False, False]]
```

Answer (score 2):

In tensorflow 2, you can convert the tensors to numpy array first and compare them using `np.array_equal.`

```
t1 = t1.numpy()
t2 = t2.numpy()
res = np.array_equal(t1, t2)
```

Comment: Actually, you even don't need the call to `numpy()`, numpy will automatically convert the tensors.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I implemented it:

```
y = tf.constant([0, 0, 0, 0])
not_equal_t = tf.not_equal(y, x)
reduce_t = tf.reduce_all(not_equal_t, axis=2) --> This will return the [True, False] that I looked for

# The rest will return the values 
where_t = tf.where(reduce_t)
gather_t = tf.gather_nd(x, where_t)
```